# Should MACROs be avoided when making a library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, static-libraries

The library offers a class to be derived from with the derived class as a template argument.

Example:

```
class userclass : public lib::superclass<userclass>
{}
```

As you can see its quite a lot to type. And the "userclass" should always derive as public for it to work correctly. So i came up with two MACROs looking like this:

```
#define SUPER(x) public lib::superclass<x>
#define SUPERCLASS(x) class x : public lib::superclass<x>
```

The user can now type either of.

```
class userclass : SUPER(userclass)
{}

SUPERCLASS(userclass)
{}
```

But the main problem is that the macros SUPER and SUPERCLASS exist in the users global namespace as quick as the header is included.

Can/should i:

1. Have a way of preserving the namespace requirement but still defaulting to public derives?
2. Use the macros as they are.
3. Simply require the user to write out the full "public lib::superclass".

I'm using vs 11 and the library is targeted against windows developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first rule of using macros is "Don't, if there's any other solution". In this case, there is another solution, so get rid of them.

Secondly, your macros do way more harm than good, because people have no idea what they expand to by just reading it, whereas the full definition does. Seriously, you're saving a truly minute number of characters for a truly hideous cost in readability. It's far superior to simply write out the inheritance.

Comment: I do a lot of maintenance work.  Macro users are somewhere on the ladder below terrorists, drug-dealers, child-abusers and PHP developers.

Comment: @MartinJames: And which one is on the top, the terrorists or the PHP developers? ;-)

Comment: To be honest, I think that the child abusers are lower than the PHP, though there isn't a lot in it.

Answer (score 2):

That really isn't a lot to type. I've seen a lot longer lines that shouldn't be shortened. Hiding it with a macro just obfuscates your code. If I take a quick look at your `SUPERCLASS(userclass) {}`, I can pretty much guess that it's a class (I don't like to use a library based on guesses) but I don't know if it or its parent is called `userclass` (or neither) or what kind of inheritance it's using. It means you have to document it and you force people to look it up when they need it.

So the correct answer is option 3 - don't use macros.

<sup>If you really really really need to use a macro in your library, give it a library specific prefix. That's as close as you'll get to a namespaced macro.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I vote for 3. Simply require the user to write out the full "public lib::superclass".

Macros in libraries *may* be useful if:

- there is really a lot to write,
- something has to be written several times
- or you want to hide an ugly implementation detail and the language doesn't allow you to do otherwise.

But in your case:

- not so much to write,
- yes, you have to put the class name twice,
- you do not want to hide the fact that you are subclassing, or even that you are writing a class!

I don't think that the duplication of the class name - the one positive point - is worth it. Particularly because you will hide the `class` keyword and cause quite some confusion on the reader.

Anyway, if a library uses macros it is customary to put the library name in front of all macros:

```
#define MY_FANCY_LIBRARY_NAME_SUPER(x) public lib::superclass<x>
```

But now you are not saving so much typing...

PS: Remember the golden rule of programming:

> Code is written once but read forever, thus it should be easy to read, more than easy to write.